# Error Launching Android Activity From Library Project

Tags: android, android-activity, project, launch

I am trying to launch an activity from an Android library project from the main project.

The setup is this:
- A `MainActivity.class` in package `com.example.main`
- A `LibraryActivity.class` in package `com.example.library` that's selected as main packages's library
- I want to launch `LibraryActivity.class` from `MainActivity.class`

I used the following intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LibraryActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Eclipse didn't give me errors and showed that `LibraryActivity.class` is in package `com.example.library`.

However, when I ran the code it gave me an error:

```
10-24 18:27:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(7887): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/sdcard0/image.jpg }} to activity {com.example.main/com.example.main.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.main/com.example.library.LibraryActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I tried defining the whole path of the class in android manifest to no avail.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.library.LibraryActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: there error has to do with starting an activity for a result. change you call to `startActivityForResult()` and define an empty `onActivityResult` method and see what happens.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I tried using startActivityForResult() instead and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Show your `LibraryActivity` declare in the manifest of your library.Have it have any intent filter or have the attribute exported="true".

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the whole package and activity name in the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.library.LibraryActivity.class);
```

and set exported as true in the manifest